# How to resize video lightbox popup in wordpress?

Tags: theme-development, css, responsive, lightbox

I am using videolightbox in WordPress.

Video Popup size is too big [see here](https://www.styrouae.com/media-gallery-videos/#iLightbox[gallery]/0) almost covering the whole page.

I want to change the pop-up size to a smaller one, at the same time I would like to keep the responsiveness of the page.

Can you please help?

Comment: I have edited my Question to make it more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the avada-documentation:

```
https://theme-fusion.com/support/documentation/avada-documentation/ -> Menu -> Extra -> Videos In Lightbox -> How To Set Video Size in Fusion Theme Options
```

**How To Set Video Size in Fusion Theme Options**

Step 1 – Navigate to the Avada > Theme Options tab.

Step 2 – Go to the Lightbox tab, and locate the Slideshow Video Width and Height options. Set the width and height of your video by entering a pixel value into the corresponding setting. For example,1280px for the width and 720px for the height.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is I have an older version of Avada in which I don't see any options to change width and height.